# Unable to Register the Channel URI in store service engagement manager

Tags: push-notification, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

I was trying to implement the logic to get the notification from windows dev center using below link [Send Push Notification to your app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/send-push-notifications-to-your-apps-customers%22)

But when I am trying to register the Notification channel It shows the Error message like

> Unable to get ChannelUri. Platform::Exception:A Notification channel request for the provided application identifier is in progress. With Error code  -2143420157

Can any one help me to solve this issues?

Comment: You might try [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to monitor the request progress and check where it gets stuck.